# check if image contains mouse location

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSCustomView with an NSImage placed inside it at a custom rectangle. How can I check if a point is within this image in my mousedown event?

Something like this:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
        NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
        if ([myImage containspoint:point]) {
           ...do stuff...
```

Comment: I know I could use a rectangle, but the image has transparent areas that should not contain the point

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Your clicked point is in image's rect with `NSPointInRect` like this:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint point = [self convertPoint: [theEvent locationInWindow] fromView: nil];

    if (NSPointInRect(point, imageRect)) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```